# How to keep height and width in a defined ratio in python with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to build a game to teach myself a bit about programming and i have no idea how to keep height and width in a defined ratio like 16:9. I would like to have it resizable.

I've tried to make the height dependent to the width.

```
import pygame, sys 
from pyame.locals import * 

pygame.init() 

FPS = 60 #frames per second setting 
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock() 

winwidth = 1600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((winwidth, winwidth * 0.5625‬), pygame.RESIZABLE) 

while True: # the main game loop     
    screen.fill(white) 
    pygame.display.update()     
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

I don't know if this is a proper way to do it. The error message is always:
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((winwidth, winwidth * 0.5625\u202c), pygame.RESIZABLE) 
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

I have no clue how pygame handels itself internally, so i can't image why there are more characters in the error message than in the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message is telling you, you have some odd extra character after your 0.5625.  It is [u202c](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm).  If you paste your code into Notepad++ and change the character encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI, you get this:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((winwidth, winwidth * 0.5625â€¬), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

If you remove this extra character, things should start working.